# Como inserir link no botão

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

Boas,

como faço pra inserir um link em um botão tentei da forma abaixo e não funcionou.

```
@IBAction func urlDisplay(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(String:"http://www.quatenus.co.ao")!)
}
```

[image: Print]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Swift 4 o código ficaria assim:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://www.quatenus.co.ao")!)
```

No seu código não está com erro, o XCode apenas está avisando que houve uma atualização na chamada da função (apenas shared)

Answer (score 2):

Usando o Swift 3 o código ficaria desta forma:

```
@IBAction func urlDisplay(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.quatenus.co.ao/")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ops. o Xcode da erro de:

 'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead

Comment: Esta mensagem é um warning e não um erro. Eu compilei o código no iOS 10 e funcionou normalmente. Você pode fazer a alteração que o Xcode está sugerindo sem nenhum problema.